# Remove Gmail contacts from SMS contacts Samsung Galaxy S9?

Tags: contacts, sms, gmail

I have a Samsung Galaxy S9 and when I try to send a SMS message to someone I have to search through all my Gmail contacts that for some reason appear on the app along with my phone contacts. I don't send mails through the message app. There is no menu in the messaging app that lets me hide the Gmail contacts. Is there any way to make the messaging app only show the contacts I have on my phone?